# $\nabla f \hspace{0,1cm}\text{sgn}(f)=?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ a real function. Is it possible to represent $\nabla f \hspace{0,1cm}\text{sgn}(f)$ as a gradient of something, so

$$\nabla f \hspace{0,1cm}\text{sgn}(f)= \nabla ?$$

Comment: What about $\nabla |f|$ ?

Comment: I thought so too, but it is $$\nabla |f|= \nabla (f^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\nabla f}{|f|},$$ which is different from $\nabla f \hspace{0,1cm} \text{sgn}(f)$ or am I wrong?

Comment: Please use parentheses $\nabla((f^2)^{1/2}) = \frac{1}{2 (f^2)^{1/2}} 2 f \nabla f = \text{sgn}(f) \nabla f$, but it is a strange way to obtain it.

Comment: Thanks you're right!